# If $H$ and $G/H$ are $p$-groups then $G$ is a $p$-group.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Please verify:

If $H$ is a $p$-group, then $|H| = p^r$, for some integer $r$.
If $G/H$ is a $p$-group, then $|G/H| = p^s$, for some integer $s$.
But the cardinality of a quotient set is the index, then $[G:H] = p^s$.

So we have $|G| = p^s . p^r = p^{r+s}$ and then $G$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: It's correct, but in my opinion, it's better to say "the order of a quotient group is its index" instead of "the cardinality of a quotient set is the index", since it's given that $G / H$ is a group (not merely a set of cosets), and indeed, you're using the fact that it is a $p$-group to assert that its order is is $p^s$.

Comment: You're right, I don't even know why in that part I wrote for sets instead of groups.

Comment: @Alnitak Just a small point in my opinion in the proof you should write: "Since $H$ is a $p$- group therefore $\vert H \vert = p^r$ instead of  If $H$ is a $p$-group, then $|H| = p^r$ " .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that $G$ is finite is redundant; a $p$-group is a group where every element has order a (finite) power of $p$ or, which is the same, if for every element $x$, $x^{p^a}=1$, for some $a>0$.

Let $x\in G$; then $(xH)^{p^a}=H$, for some $a$, because $G/H$ is a $p$-group. This means that $x^{p^a}\in H$, but then $(x^{p^a})^{p^b}=1$, for some $b$, because $H$ is a $p$-group.